# Running a custom Magento script with CLI ( OOP approach )

Tags: magento-1.9, php

My programming background is in different languages so I am tackling php and magento and learning as I go.  so this may be a php question more than magento , but it would be good to know how people write scripts like this.

```
require_once '../../../app/Mage.php';

Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
$newStoreId = Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID;
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(newStoreId));

class myClass
{

    public function doStuff(){
        $installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup', 'catalog_setup');
        var_dump($this->installer);
//etc.. 
}

$obj = new myClass();
$obj-> doStuff();
```

$this->installer  is always null.  I have tried all sorts of different variations.  I don't want $installer to have any initial value , but I have tried declaring as a public variable.

How can I set this value ( $installer )  inside the class and have access to it inside the class?

I feel like I am fundamentally missing something.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you initialised myClass?

Comment: yes @AndréFerraz .  Sorry  I have edited code to show that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps just do this ?

```
require_once '../../../app/Mage.php';
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
$newStoreId = Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID;
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(newStoreId));

class myClass
{
    protected $_installer;

    function setInstaller($installer) {
        $this->_installer = $installer;
    }

    function getInstaller() {
        return $this->_installer;
    }

    public function doStuff(){
        $installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup', 'catalog_setup');
        $this->setInstaller($installer);

        var_dump($this->getInstaller());
    }
}

$obj = new myClass();
$obj->doStuff();
```

Comment: Sorry , the question was: How can I set this value ( $installer ) inside the class and have access to it inside the class?  The whole idea is to do this in an OOP way - I know how to do that.  Thank you.

Comment: I updated my answer. Now, you can access to $_installer with its getter inside the class. Is it that you want ?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a closer look at your example:

`public function doStuff(){
        $installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup', 'catalog_setup');
        var_dump($this->installer);`

should be:

`public function doStuff(){
        $installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup', 'catalog_setup');
        var_dump($installer);`

or

`public function doStuff(){
        $this->installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup', 'catalog_setup');
        var_dump($this->installer);`

Note that you're setting `$installer` as a variable and then attempting to reference it through a class member `$this->classMember`

For more information on variable scope in PHP see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php